# Query on RxJava thread scheduling

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I am new to RxJava2. In the code below, I am unable to understand how is the subscriber working on a background thread, even though the Observable/Flowable is emitting on the main thread and there is no Scheduler specified (using subscribeOn(Schedulers.*) calls). The full code can be found in [this github repo.](https://github.com/kaushikgopal/RxJava-Android-Samples/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/morihacky/android/rxjava/fragments/PollingFragment.java)

```
@OnClick(R.id.btn_start_simple_polling)
public void onStartSimplePollingClicked() {

    _log("onStartSimplePollingClicked called on ");  //MAIN THREAD

    final int pollCount = POLL_COUNT;

    Disposable d = Observable
          .interval(INITIAL_DELAY, POLLING_INTERVAL, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
          .map(this::_doNetworkCallAndGetStringResult)
          .take(pollCount)
          .doOnSubscribe(subscription -> {
              _log(String.format("Start simple polling - %s", _counter));     //MAIN THREAD
          })
          .subscribe(taskName -> {
              _log(String.format(Locale.US,
                                 "Executing polled task [%s] now time : [xx:%02d]",
                                 taskName,
                                 _getSecondHand()));
          });

    _disposables.add(d);
}

private String _doNetworkCallAndGetStringResult(long attempt) {
    try {
        _log("_doNetworkCallAndGetStringResult called on "); //BACKGROUND THREAD
        if (attempt == 4) {
            // randomly make one event super long so we test that the repeat logic waits
            // and accounts for this.
            Thread.sleep(9000);
        }
        else {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        }

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Timber.d("Operation was interrupted");
    }
    _counter++;

    return String.valueOf(_counter);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you did not specify a scheduler on which to subscribe RxJava defaults to a synchronous subscription. So the calls to `onSubscribe` and `doOnSubscribe` happen on the main thread.

However the `Observable.interval` operator requires either an implicit or an explicit scheduler to broadcast the `onNext` events. Since you did not specify a scheduler it defaults to `Schedulers.computation()`.
After the interval fires it continues to call `_doNetworkCallAndGetStringResult` on the same computation thread, thus happening in the background.

Answer (score 0):

RxJava by default run syncroniously but some operators as @Kiskae already told you as interval, delay or some others

If you want to run a pipeline asyncroniously you will have to use observerOn which will make run the pipeline in another thread once is put in your pipeline

```
 /**
     * Once that you set in your pipeline the observerOn all the next steps of your pipeline will be executed in another thread.
     * Shall print
     * First step main
     * Second step RxNewThreadScheduler-2
     * Third step RxNewThreadScheduler-1
     */
    @Test
    public void testObservableObserverOn() throws InterruptedException {
        Subscription subscription = Observable.just(1)
                .doOnNext(number -> System.out.println("First step " + Thread.currentThread()
                        .getName()))
                .observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .doOnNext(number -> System.out.println("Second step " + Thread.currentThread()
                        .getName()))
                .observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .doOnNext(number -> System.out.println("Third step " + Thread.currentThread()
                        .getName()))
                .subscribe();
        new TestSubscriber((Observer) subscription)
                .awaitTerminalEvent(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
```

or use subscribeOn which it will make your pipeline run in the thread that you specify

```
/**
 * Does not matter at what point in your pipeline you set your subscribeOn, once that is set in the pipeline,
 * all steps will be executed in another thread.
 * Shall print
 * First step RxNewThreadScheduler-1
 * Second step RxNewThreadScheduler-1
 */
@Test
public void testObservableSubscribeOn() throws InterruptedException {
    Subscription subscription = Observable.just(1)
            .doOnNext(number -> System.out.println("First step " + Thread.currentThread()
                    .getName()))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .doOnNext(number -> System.out.println("Second step " + Thread.currentThread()
                    .getName()))
            .subscribe();
    new TestSubscriber((Observer) subscription)
            .awaitTerminalEvent(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

You can see more examples about async rxJava here https://github.com/politrons/reactive/blob/master/src/test/java/rx/observables/scheduler/ObservableAsynchronous.java